# How to transform each element from Flow<List<User>> and return new Flow<List<UserWithNumber>>

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The difficulty is that I get the number wrapped in a flow.

Implementation of UserWithNumber

```
data class UserWithNumber(val user: User, val number: Int)
```

Implementation of users functions:

```
fun getUsers(): Flow<List<User>> {
    //return users
}

fun getNumberForUser(userId: Long): Flow<Int> {
    //return number
}

fun getUsersWithNumber(): Flow<List<UserWithNumber>> {
    return getUsers()
        //TODO transform every User to UserWithNumber
}
```

in RxJava i can easily achieve that with flatMapIterable and toList().

```
fun getUsersWithNumber(): Observable<List<UserWithNumber>> {
    return getUsers() // return Observable<List<User>>
        .flatMapIterable { it } // unfolds list in Observable<User>
        .flatMap { it.getNumberForUser(it.id) } // make transform function to every user
        .toList() // wrap to list
}
```

How to do that with kotlin coroutines?

Comment: Why is the number wrapped in a Flow? Is it actually multiple numbers that change over time? Does UserWithNumber contain a list of numbers or do you just want the first value from the Flow?

Comment: In fact, this is a highly simplified example. In my case, the number is a value that changes often and I need a flow

Comment: See UserWithNumber class above in my answer. In other words i want to transform every user with getNumberForUser function and wrap number and user to UserWithNumber

Comment: So do you just want the first number from the flow at the time a User is emitted from the source Flow?

Comment: User number can dynamically changed in database and i need to react to changes. So easy way to get Int without Flow isnt my way i think

Comment: So your resulting Flow is one that emits a new List any time any user’s number has changed, and then of course every time the source user list changes?

Comment: What are you leading to?) I'm mainly interested in, is there a solution similar to RX flatMapIterable with coroutines?

Comment: Just trying to figure out what you want. I don’t use Rx so I was trying to get a clear picture of the expected output to be able to answer.

Comment: Well, i get list of users from Room DB(sqllite ORM). UserEntity in Room has id, and few other fields. After getting the list of users, I want for each user in the list to get some special value (int type number). This value(number) stores in other table and depends on others values in table. That values can be changed in the time and special number can be changed with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
fun getUsersWithNumber(): Flow<List<UserWithNumber>> {
    return getUsers().map { userList ->
        userList.map { user ->
           // transform User to UserWithNumber here 
           // (possibly with an extension function?)
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not sure is how you want to do the transformation, since based on what you've posted you have `getNumberForUser` which returns a `Flow<Int>`, not a `Flow<UserWithNumber>`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is using a suspend function.
Probably you're not needed to flow for just getting a userNumber.

Change method signature to `suspend fun getNumberForUser(userId: Long): Int`

Then you can easily map your `Flow<User>` to `Flow<UserWithNumber>`.

```
fun getUsersWithNumber(): Flow<List<UserWithNumber>> {
    return getUsers()
        .map { users -> 
            users.map { getNumberForUser(it.id) }
        }
}
```